# Allow window to format before printing

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I use the javascript code below to pass an element ID to a method, which will then format that particular ID in a separate window and then print.  The problem I am having is that the print dialogue box is opening up before the window completes formatting the new page.  I then have to cancel the print dialogue, then allow the page to format, and then initiate the print again.  How can I ensure that the page completes formatting before the print dialogue box opens?  Thanks.

```
function printPartOfPage(elementId) {   
    var printHeader = document.getElementById('header');
    var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var windowUrl = 'NewWindow';
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
    var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=20,top=200');
    printWindow.document.write('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>');    
    printWindow.document.write('<link href='+sURL+'css/style.css rel="stylesheet">');   
    printWindow.document.write('<link href='+sURL+'css/print.css rel="stylesheet">');   
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');    
    printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
}
```

Comment: I guess the function is called in the body onload event or in the window.onload ?

Comment: Have you ever heard about Media Print Stylesheets, no need to do this. Heck you even include it on the new window.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, I have no experience with Media Print Stylesheets, but I see how that could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to print a few miliseconds after the page formats.

```
...
setTimeout(function(){
    printWindow.print();
}, 1)
```

Or, you can wait until the window finishes loading:

```
printWindow.document.addEventListener('load', function(){
    printWindow.print();
})
```